# BlockInput VBA/EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Preciso bloquear os comandos na minha macro no Excel. Estou usando a seguinte função:

```
Public Declare Function BlockInput Lib "user32" (ByVal fblock As Long) As Long
```

No computador com win 64 bit funciona normalmente mas quando passei a planilha para um PC de 32 bit a função blockinput deixou de funcionar, porém sem apresentar nenhum erro e o restante do programa funciona normalmente. É extremamente necessário pra mim que funcione essa função e bloqueie a entrada após a execução da macro, mesmo no Pc de 32 bit.
Alguma idéia do que possa estar acontecendo? Obrigado!

Comment: Segundo a documentação da função [BlockInput](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-blockinput) elá só funciona em plataformas Windows 2000 Professional para as camadas Cliente e Windows 2000 Server para as camadas Servidor. A documentação não menciona limitações quanto ao tamanho da palavra, porém da a entender que essa função é suportada em máquinas com palavra de 32bits pois função está declarada na bibliotéca `User32.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

Com um teste para verificar a versão do Windows e do pacote Office:

```
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931754/7690982
Sub versao()
    #If Win64 Then
        #If VBA7 Then
            MsgBox "Win 64 and Office 64"        ' HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\YourApp
        #Else
            MsgBox "Win 64 and Office 32"        ' HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\YourApp
        #End If
    #Else
        MsgBox "Win 32 and Office 32"            ' HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\YourApp
    #End If
End Sub
```

O Office e o Windows do teste são 32 bits e o código a seguir funcionou para o `BlockInput`:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function BlockInput Lib "User32" (ByVal fBlock As Boolean) As Boolean '64 Bit
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) '64 Bit
#Else
    Public Declare Function BlockInput Lib "User32" (ByVal fBlock As Boolean) As Boolean '32 Bit
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) '32 Bit
#End If

Sub teste_blockinput()
    On Error GoTo Sair
    BlockInput (True)
    'Código Aqui
    Sleep 10000 'Sleep de 10 segundos
Sair:
    BlockInput (False)
End Sub
```